# tabindex looping through tabbable <li> tags inside a popout

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

In my code, this `<ul>` is rendering in a popout form, and I am able to tab through the `<li>` tags for accessibility reasons. However, one issue that I'm facing is that I can't loop back through the `<li>` tags after I've reached the last `<li>` tag. The first time I reach the end of the `<li>` tag, it moves me to the first `<li>` tag, which is the expected behavior. But then when I reach the last `<li>` tag again, it gets stuck there and doesn't let me loop over again. Any help will be much appreciated.

```html
<ul class="filter-group__list  filter-group__list--chips" tabindex="0" data-layout="3col"><li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--XS--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="XS" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=XS" data-value-escaped="XS" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--XS--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          XS
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

<li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--S--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="S" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=S" data-value-escaped="S" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--S--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          S
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

<li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--M--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="M" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=M" data-value-escaped="M" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--M--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          M
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

<li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--L--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="L" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=L" data-value-escaped="L" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--L--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          L
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

<li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--XL--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="XL" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=XL" data-value-escaped="XL" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--XL--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          XL
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

<li class="
    filter-item
     filter-item--chip
  " tabindex="1">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.v.option.size--XXL--top-bar">
    <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" name="filter.v.option.size" value="XXL" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" tabindex="-1" data-filter="filter.v.option.size=XXL" data-value-escaped="XXL" id="filter--filter.v.option.size--XXL--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-item__chip" tabindex="0">
          XXL
        </div></div>
  </label>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Personally, I would avoid this as it goes against accessibility guidelines for accessing other aspects of the page. Did you know that SHIFT+TAB moves the focus in the opposite direction of just TAB?

Comment: IMHO, I agree as well, you shouldn't loop back because in theory this restricts the user because then they cannot tab onto anything else (ie in their browser Chrome)... it traps them. I wouldn't be shocked if browsers fight this too, in the interest of maintaining accessibility.

Comment: In any case, I find it strange that you have `tabindex="1"` on your `<li>`'s. I would think all of them would be `tabindex=0` and act as your primary tab area that you'd want. Everything else for the given item should be untabbable. In your children you have a `tabindex=0` on each `filter-item__chip`... why? This is creating a double-tab situation for me when running your sample.

Comment: I could see a "trapped focus loop" like this as being useful in a kiosk environment; is that what you're building? There it would make sense, because there is nothing else to tab to. However, locking a browser down like that is challenging. How much fight do you want?